# How to show app icon when new contact added

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I am creating an app in which I want to show my app icon in front of every contact if contact is associated with my app like in WhatsApp. I have searched a lot but didn't find any appropriate solution.

Comment: show us what you already have, what you tried, and explain what did not work, and show error messages, if there are any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch all the contacts from your phone like this.

```
 public void getNumber(ContentResolver cr)
        {
         mItems = new ArrayList<String>();
         Cursor phones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

            while (phones.moveToNext())
            {
              String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
              String phoneNumberString = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
              phoneNumberString.replace(" ", "");
             contactName.add(name);
              contactNumber.add(phoneNumberString);
              mItems.add(name);
            }
            phones.close();
        }
```

now send all these contacts to your server, compare each mobile number in your server database, and list only the contacts that are found in your server.

**You need to maintain your own database, when registering user, save his number and while comparing, compare the fetched number to the register member's number in your own database**

Comment: Please read question carefully, i want to show app icon in front of every contact like whatsapp, i have compare all contacts already

Comment: You have finished doing the main thing and are stuck on a silly thing. Use a custom listview and hide the icon if they are not using the app. Damn.

Comment: I am talking about the main phone contact list, have you ever used whatsapp?

Comment: OHHh sorry i got your question wrong. U should have expressed in that way buddy.